# Speeding ticket in Germany

Tags: tickets, germany, driving, fines

I received a notice informing me of a speeding ticket in Germany and have lost the payment information.  If Imdo not pay the ticket, will there be any repercussions the next t8me I go to Germany? I have read there is a 6 month statute of limitations on these offenses, is this true as well?

Comment: What is your citizenship? The answer may be different for EU and non-EU citizens

Comment: The statutory period of limitation only runs until you have been properly notified about the penalty and the period for speeding tickets is 3 or 6 months depending on the type of penalty, which again depends on how fast you were driving. The period of limitation does not mean that the demand for payment is dropped if you manage to evade payment for a few months. Depending on your place of residence, the penalty can also be enforced abroad, usually bundled with several other fees and charges.

Comment: If you were driving a rental car, the rental company will likely pay the ticket, then turn around and charge your credit card.

Comment: *Who* sent you this notice? A governmental authority or your rental car agency? Whomever it was, you can most likely phone them up to receive another copy of the payment information.

Answer (score 3):

The **Vollstreckungsverjährung** for charges up to 1000 Euro is three years.

However, several measures of the authorities can extend that period ad infinitum. For example, if the authorities don't start that *Vollstreckung* because they found you left Germany. In that case, they will bill you on your next visit.